# checked unchecked parent child exception in overriden method

Tags: java, exception

we can't throw checked parent exception from overriden method, but we can throw unchecked exceptions, but while throwing "Exception" from Child2 class gives error (although throwing unchecked exception ArithmeticException from parent class)but while i am trying to throw RunTimeException then code runs properly, for more details go throw code.

```
class Parent {
    void msg() throws ArithmeticException { //ArithmeticException is child of //RuntimeException and both are unchecked exceptions
        System.out.println("parent");
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    void msg() throws RuntimeException { //not gives any compile time error
        System.out.println("child");
    }
}

class Child2 extends Parent {
    void msg() throws Exception { //gives compile time error
        System.out.println("child");
    }
}

class Test1{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Parent p = new Parent();
        p.msg();
        Parent c = new Child();
        c.msg();
        Child d = new Child();
        d.msg();
        Child2 e = new Child2();
        e.msg();
    }       
}
```

please explain if i am wrong somewhere.

Comment: I'm not sure at all what your question text is trying to say.  In `Child2` you cannot throw a checked exception because the signature of `Parent` does not allow (declare) it.  That's it.

Comment: ArithmeticException is a unchecked exception, so it should not give any compile time error in case of child2

Comment: If it's unchecked then why did you declare it in the method signature? If you declared it the signature of the parent method, shouldn't you declare it in the override?

Comment: `throws Exception` is an antipattern.

Comment: @LewBloch we can throw unchecked exceptions also and i didn't catch u properly, what do u want to ask, i am generating my ArithmaticException that's why i have to throw it, i think i answered you.

Comment: I didn't ask about throwing it, I asked about making it part of the signature. Have you tried adding the declaration of that exception to the override? Also, the second-person nominative pronoun in English is spelled "you", not "u".

Comment: @LewBloch if we remove all exceptions from signature then it will work fine, you are right at that place, but i just did't able to understand why this code given me compile time error although ArthmeticException is unchecked exception.

Comment: Have you tried adding the declaration of that exception to the override?